# Square Connect API - API - order

Tags: api, square

I am developing an application to integrate with square, and I can create orders, but when I consult them with:

https://connect.squareup.com/v2/locations/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/orders/batch-retrieve

it brings me `null`

Answer (score 0):

From the docs: `Retrieves a set of Orders by their IDs. Only orders that have been successfully charged are included in the response.` I'm betting that either you haven't charged the orders yet, or aren't providing the right ids to retrieve.

https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2#endpoint-batchretrieveorders